# Get links to open in new window with Squeezebox Portfolio Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, portfolio

So I've been monkeyinag around with this script:
https://codyhouse.co/demo/squeezebox-portfolio-template/index.html

I like the look of it so I went with it.  I got rid of the show projects part and now have a nice scrolling portfolio, but I'd like is for the name and description in the .project-info to actually link to an external page rather than open the modal window.  Obviously I tried just adding a link and while you can choose to open in a new tab it it won't go to the url.  I also removed the `<a href="#0">` to git red of the modal window alltogether.

Comment: FInd the `<a href.....` element in the developer tools' "elements" tab (Chrome), then go to the "event listeners" tab for that element, click "click" and then remove the `div.cd-projects.......` event, replace the `href` of the original link with the URL of the file you want to redirect to, then repeat these changes across your actual files, so that they are permanent.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly!

Comment: ok stupid follow up, i figured when you removed the `div.cd` you would just save a new .js file like when editing a .css file.  how do i make these changes permanent?

Comment: Don't you have access to 'main.js' ? If you do, just edit the file normally. Otherwise you will have to override/remove the event.

Comment: Ok, I got it, i thought you could save it directly through chrome